# Summing datediff together

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently, my access output is like this

| FirstName | LastName | NoOfHours | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chloe | Wang | 9 | $45 |
| Chloe | Wang | 9 | $25 |
| May | Chan | 18 | $55 |
| May | Chan | 11 | $55 |

I am trying to group them together to become

```
| FirstName | LastName | NoOfHours | Total  |
| --------  | -------- |-----------|--------|
| Chloe     | Wang     | 18        |$70     |
| May       | Chan     | 29        |$110    |
```

My NoOfHours field was calculated by using datediff. I had tried to use group by to put them together but there wasn't any difference.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, SUM(). (Show us your query attempt.)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your current query, you would do something like this:

```
select firstname, lastname,
       sum(datediff( . . . )), sum(amount)
from t
group by firstname, lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select firstname,lastname, sum(noofhours)noofhours, sum(total)Total
from mytable
group by firstname,lastname
```

You can also put `datediff()` condition in place of `noofhours` within `sum()`